# Pandas-Profiling in text

Tags: dataframe, text, nlp, profiling

I want to apply profiling in text, but before I have to clean and recognize the most frequente words. But when I apply nltk it returns a list and I can not create a profiling. Is there someway to do this?

```
corpus = []
for i in range(17000):
  review = re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]', ' ', dataset['Descrição Reparo'][i])
  review = review.lower().split()
  review = [word for word in review if not word in set(stopwords.words('portuguese'))]
  review = ' '.join(review)
  corpus.append(review)

cv = CountVectorizer()
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus).toarray()
```

Answer (score 0):

hope it will work

feature=cv.get_feature_names()

[image]

now you can use pandas profiling